# Avoid images to stack on mobile site

Tags: html, css, image, mobile, squarespace

I just started learning coding and I decided to design my website using `squarespace` and `www.rociodelfa.com`.

My main problem is that on my **inspiration page** I have a gallery of images that need to follow a cohesive order and I want to fix the amount of images per line but it is not the same for every line.

When opened on a mobile device the images are stacked. How do I change that?

Comment: When you have mobile-first websites, the images stack when the width of the screen decreases. If you can add a codepen or fiddle then we might be able to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the code I have attached.

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 20%; /* Let's assume you want 5 pictures in a row, so 100%/5 = 20% */
  float: left;
  padding: 10px;

  }
.wrapper img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
</div>
```